# UIImage redrawing efficiency

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an UIimage with some text drawn on the image. I know the exact coordinates of the text rectangle on the image. When the image pan event is fired, I check if the pan is starting with a click on the rectangle in the image where there is text.

If (pan started from a click on the rectangle) then

I get the Pan translate coordinates and move the rectangle. So what I actually do is get the new coordinates and redraw the image with the rectangle in the new position. this gives the panning effect of the rectangle (for other reasons I cannot use a label but have to redraw).

This works perfectly, except that if the panning is done "too fast" there is an elasticity effect and the rectangle kind of is lagging behind. In theory I neednot redraw the whole image but rather only the intersection of the old and new rectangles. This I think will certainly make it more smoother.

Question: How to make it fast.
//Code where I redraw

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
  [img drawInRect: CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2);
  CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y, myRect.size.width, myRect.size.height));

   UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
   CurrentImageView.Image = theImage;
```

I personally think that the most time consuming step here is

```
[img drawInRect: CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
```

It is illogical to be redrawing the whole image. I want to take a old image and just redraw a part of the image and assign it to the view controller. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance,
prasad.

Comment: Why not just place the image and text in separate views or layers and avoid having to redraw them at all? Just draw them once and move the layers relative to one another.

Comment: Indeed. Avoiding manual drawing via layers is the key to iOS drawing performance.

Comment: Saying "for other reasons I cannot use a label but have to redraw" is a bad justification and means we have to rely on your initial assessment of the situation, which could well be wrong..

Comment: @Paul.s you are right I was mistaken on the reason not to use a label. Finally ended up using a label and it works perfectly.